# Ошибка при занесении словаря в базу данных sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite3, dict

Пытаюсь внести в бд sqlite3 значения и получаю ошибку
`sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type` 
Понимаю, что ошибка во втором параметре, который является словарём. В python имею такую структуру:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stickers_places (weapon_name TEXT, stickers BLOB)''')

cur.executemany('INSERT INTO stickers_places VALUES (weapon_name, stickers)', stickers_places)

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Словарь выглядит таким образом:

```
stickers_places = [
('AK-47', {
    0: 'normal',
    1: 'bad',
    2: 'normal',
    3: 'top',
}),
('M4A4', {
    0: 'normal',
    1: 'normal',
    2: 'top',
    3: 'bad',
}),
...
]
```

Что конкретно я делаю неправильно. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте словарь преобразовать в строку, из строки получить байты (т.к. это **B**LOB) и их поместить

Думаю, так:

```
import json

...

for name, stickers in stickers_places:
    stickers_data = json.dumps(stickers)
    stickers_blob = sqlite3.Binary(stickers_data.encode('utf-8'))
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO stickers_places VALUES (weapon_name, stickers)', [name, stickers_blob])
...
```

---

Кст, у `json` ключи могут быть только строками, поэтому у того словаря ключи перестанут быть числами, если это важно, то можно через `str` сделать строку из словаря, а парсить через `ast`.

```
import json
print(json.dumps({
    0: 'normal',
    1: 'bad',
    2: 'normal',
    3: 'top',
}))
# {"0": "normal", "1": "bad", "2": "normal", "3": "top"}

print(str({
    0: 'normal',
    1: 'bad',
    2: 'normal',
    3: 'top',
}))
# {0: 'normal', 1: 'bad', 2: 'normal', 3: 'top'}

import ast
d = ast.literal_eval(str({
    0: 'normal',
    1: 'bad',
    2: 'normal',
    3: 'top',
}))
print(d)
{0: 'normal', 1: 'bad', 2: 'normal', 3: 'top'}
```

Comment: Получаю ошибку AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'. И не особо понял как мне сохранить цифры цифрами. Спасибо

Comment: @IIIyTH1K, а ну да, там список а не словарь, уберите `.items()`, обновил ответ. Насчет цифр, вместо `json.dumps` использовать `str`, а, при разборе вместо `json.loads` использовать `ast.literal_eval`